# Android Glide can't resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using this version of Glide on two project

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

I don't know how and why but Android Studio can't resolve symbol "asBitmap() and GlideAnimation

```
 Glide.with(this).load(path).asBitmap().override(200, 200).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), resource);
            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            mImageViewProfilePic.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            // Do something.
            mImageViewProfilePic.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder_photo_profile));
        }
    });
```

Now it ask me to use this like I was in version 4+ ?

```
public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
```

Even after that it can't resolve this method....

Then I tried to remove Glide library but the project still find import (except "import com.bumptech.glide.request.animation.GlideAnimation")

I cleaned, rebuild, invalidate cache.... I have the same thing of my other projet who works perfectly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    jumboMode true
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "fr.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}


buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "PRE_PROD", "false"
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '.D'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

ext.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = "27.0.2"
ext.GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION = "11.8.0"


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
implementation 'com.android.support:design:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:' + GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:' + GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:' + GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

// Graph Lib
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'


// Android NetWorking Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'

// JSON Parsing
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

//The string required for Firebase integration
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:' + GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:' + GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}


//SMOOCH
implementation 'io.smooch:core:latest.release'
implementation 'io.smooch:ui:latest.release'

implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'

// AWESOOOOOOME TOAST LIB
implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:1.0.2'

// PHONE NUMBER LIB
implementation('com.lamudi.phonefield:phone-field:0.1.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

// PHOTO LOADER
implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**UPDATE 1**

I see in my external library that gradle is building the version 4.6.1
[image]

I tried to remove .iml and .idea folder ... no change
Glide still bug, still here even if I remove the lib.

**UPDATE 2**

```
    compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '4.6.1'
```

Then I updated Glide's methods in my code and now I have this message:

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcms
```

I tried to change GOOGLE_PLAY_VERSION to gms and firebase to the same but no change.

[image]

Comment: Try to use latest version and see if it works. The latest version is 4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

you have to use it right after with like this

```
Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
```

This will solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Do not use compile. Use implementation:

```
implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Also, verify if you have "offline work" checked.

Comment: Ok now I have "implementation"
I tried everything with "offline work" checked and not checked.
I think the problem come from the end of the universe. If I remove my MPchart lib, import are missing, but if I remove Glide lib, importe are still here.

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to mark down my answer. Talk about being ungrateful. Also, if you want more help, why don't you post your gradle file (build.gradle)? Do you have Maven repository set up? Have you verified the "path" variable?

Comment: My bad about mark down your answer, I didn't even notice. I update my post with my build.gradle

Comment: It's fine, mate. Just trying to reach 50 rep ;) I see nothing wrong with your gradle file. Maybe your path variable is not correct? I would log it just to make sure.

Comment: I will check later, I 'm trying to understand why Android studio still find Glide's import after I deleted the lib (clean/rebuild....)

Comment: That's because it downloads it for you from the Maven repository. If you delete the files and set Android Studio for Offline Work, he won't be able to find it.

Comment: I don't have Maven repository set up.

Comment: Then we found the problem :D Go to your project's build.gradle (not the module one) and, under "buildscript" - "repositories" add "jcenter()", "mavenCentral()" and "google()" (without the quotes). Add them under "all projects" - "repositories" as well. That should do the trick.

Comment: I Tried on my other MacBook, with a older version, just copy/past source  and add missing import, same problem, It load the wrong version/can't remove Glide.
What do you need to understand better my problem ? Maybe I did  something wrong.

Comment: Instead of implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0', try compile group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', name: 'glide', version: '4.6.1'

Comment: Maybe this resolved my problem (thx Hope you saved my day) but got a new one after updating glide's methods. (See update 2)

Comment: Great! Good news, finally :D That's because you have multiple libraries defining the same classes. It's easy to fix. In your module's build.gradle, under android{ defaultConfig {, add "multiDexEnabled = true" (without quotes)

Comment: Already added since the beginning. I'm checking others post, everyone seems to have a solution but not for me :)

BTW it's half resolve, coz I can still remove the lib on my gradle but still use glide on my code :(